# How do I make a plot for $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}2\eta_i^2 sech^2(\eta(x - 4\eta_i^2 t - x_i^0))$?

Tags: plotting

[image]

I would like to replicate a figure similar to that shown above. However, in my attempt for naively plotting two such "pulses", I get a single pulse. Why?

`Plot[Sech[x]^2 + Sech[x-1]^2, {x, -2Pi,2Pi}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

The pulses are too close together.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{Sech[x]^2 + Sech[x - a]^2,
   Sech[x]^2, Sech[x - a]^2},
  {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi + 3 a/4},
  PlotRange -> {0, 2},
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed, Dashed}],
 {{a, 1}, 0, 5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: What dictates how far they need to be spaced so that only their tails touch?

Comment: Pick a threshold (say 10^-2), then `MinValue[{x, Sech[x] < 10^-2, x > 0}, x] // N // Quiet`